# Swift Looping persistence of variables / scoping

Tags: swift, loops, memory

So this will be very abstract code however what i am doing it looping through an array of objects, calling a helper function to parse the complex object from json and insert it into an array. The issue I am having is that the object I am parsing into does not get cleared each time through the loop:

```
for item in parsedEvolutionList {
    if let abilityKey: String = item.allKeys[0] as? String{
        if let abilityData = item[abilityKey] as? NSDictionary{
            if var newAbility = EvolutionAbilityStore.SharedInstance.retreaveEvolutionAbilityByKey(abilityKey) {
                newAbility.parseFromJson(abilityData)
                if evolutionList == nil {
                    evolutionList = []
                }
                evolutionList?.append(newAbility)
            } else {
                log.warning("Atempting to parse EvolutionAbility and \(item) was not found in the store")
            }
        } else {
            log.warning("Atempting to parse EvolutionAbility and \(item) does not have data for ability to parse")
        }
    } else {
        log.warning("Atempting to parse EvolutionAbility and \(item) is formatted incorectaly")
    }
}
```

So the newAbility is an array, it contains the content of the first parsed object after the first loop, on second pass already has the content of the first pass and adds the content of the second pass, so on and so forth, then when adding to the evolution list it adds another pointer to the same object so all my objects in the evolutionList end up being objects to the same pointer. Why is newAbility persisting through iterations of the loop? that makes no sense to me with how that interferes with scoping

Answer (score 0):

Oh oh oh, the creation of the object comes from a singleton, which does persist by designe ... has nothing to do with percectance of data in the loop!